# Trying to write a program that checks a password to see if it has at least 1 Upper case and Lower case letter and 1 digit

Tags: c

Im writing code that is supposed to check if a password has 1 upper case letter, 1 lower case letter and 1 digit, But did something wrong and don't know how to fix it. Can someone help?

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char password[30];
    int len;
    int i;
    int num_alpha_num = 0;
    len = strlen(password);
    printf("Please enter Password: ");
    scanf("%s",password);
    for (i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++)
    {
        if (isalnum (password[i]))
        {
            num_alpha_num ++;
        }
    }
    if(num_alpha_num < 1)
    {
        printf("Wrong");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Done");
    }
```

EDIT: So i fixed my code by doing this:

```
  int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        char password[30];
        int len;
        int i;
        int num_alpha_num = 0;
        printf("Please enter Password: ");
        scanf("%s",password);
        len = strlen(password);
        for (i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++)
        {
            if (isalnum (password[i]))
            {
                num_alpha_num ++;
            }
        }
        if(num_alpha_num < 1)
        {
            printf("Wrong");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Done");
        }
```

But it doesn't give the results im after. The program as it it is now gives me "Done" if the passwaord as 1 upper case OR 1 lower case OR 1 digit. But i want it to check for all of them, for example: the password is wrong when it is "SS2" and right when it is "Ss2". How would i do this?

Final Code (Thanks Everyone!) :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char password[30];
    int len;
    int i;
    int num_upper_num = 0;
    int num_lower_num = 0;
    int num_digit_num = 0;
    printf("Please enter Password: ");
    scanf("%s",password);
    len = strlen(password);
    for (i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++)
    {
        if (isupper (password[i]))
        {
            num_upper_num = 1;
        }
         if (islower (password[i]))
        {
            num_lower_num = 1;
        }
         if (isdigit (password[i]))
        {
            num_digit_num = 1;
        }
    }
    if(num_upper_num + num_lower_num + num_digit_num == 3)
    {
        printf("This password is valid");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("This password is invalid");
        printf("\nA password must contain 1 upper case, 1 lower case, and 1 digit.");
    }
  
   
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: `len = strlen(password);` - `password` is uninitialized at this point.

Comment: You're taking the `strlen` of `password` *before* you get the password from the user.  Doing things out of order is common for folks new to programming.

Comment: There are other issues too, related to security, which might look like minor, but given this program is working with passwords - may be very important. Think what will happen if the user is entering a password longer than 30 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with this program. let's check them line by line.

```
char password[30];
```

When taking input, a large buffer size is generally preferred. Otherwise if the input is too long for the array, your `scanf` will cause a buffer overflow, characters will be written outside the array (more on `scanf` soon). I'd change this buffer size to 1024 but I've even seen people who make it 8192.

`int num_alpha_num = 0;` is bad for checking your specific requirement, but that comes later.

```
len = strlen(password);
```

`password` is currently uninitialized, so it will hold garbage values, god knows what the length could become. Even if you zero-initialize the buffer, `len` will be 0, because there will be a NUL terminator right at the beginning. This should come *after* input (though you have fixed this in the edit).

```
scanf("%s",password);
```

See [A beginner's guide away from `scanf`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html). In this specific case, it can cause a buffer overflow, as I previously mentioned. A better alternative is using `fgets` where you specify the max length as a parameter. See the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) on `fgets` and a few other input functions.

Now, coming to the current issue you are having:

```
    for (i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++)
    {
        if (isalnum (password[i]))
        {
            num_alpha_num ++;
        }
    }
    if(num_alpha_num < 1)
    {
        printf("Wrong");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Done");
    }
```

This uses `isalnum`, which can only check if a number is an alphanumeric character. Not what you want. To meet your requirements, one solution would be to create 3 `bool`/`_Bool` variables called `has_upper`, `has_lower`, `has_num` and set them all to false before you enter the loop. While in the loop, check for each possible case with `isupper`, `islower` and `isdigit` functions defined in `<ctype.h>` and if one of the conditions returns true, set the respective `bool` variable to `true`. At the end of the loop, check if all 3 variables are true for a correct password.

Here's an example program that demonstrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char password[1024]; // Increased buffer size
    int len;
    int i;
    
    bool has_upper = false, has_lower = false, has_num = false; // To check each requirement
    printf("Please enter Password: ");
    fgets(password, sizeof password, stdin); // Safer than scanf
    len = strlen(password); // Take length after input
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) // i <= len - 1 is a bit redundant, i < len is better
    {
        if (isupper(password[i]))
            has_upper = true;
        else if (islower(password[i]))
            has_lower = true;
        else if (isdigit(password[i]))
            has_num = true;
    }
    if(has_upper && has_lower && has_num)
        printf("Done\n");
    else
        printf("Wrong\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See If this works:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char password[30];
    int len;
    int i;
    int flagA = 0;
    int flaga = 0;
    int flag1 = 0;

    printf("Please enter Password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);
    len = strlen(password);

    for (i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++)
    {
        if ((int) password[i] > 97 && (int) password[i] < 122 )
            {
                flaga = 1;
            }
        if ((int) password[i] > 65 && (int) password[i] < 90 )
            {
                flagA = 1;
            }
        if ((int) password[i] > 48 && (int) password[i] < 57 )
            {
                flag1 = 1;
            }
    }

    if ((flaga+flagA+flag1) == 3)
    {
      printf("Done");
    } 
    else 
    {
      printf("Wrong");
    }
    return 0;
}
```